# How to remove the null values and get the table like shown below?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here i have the oracle db table like shown below:

```
name  a1     b1     c1
----  ---    ---    ---
a     z      null   null  
a     null   y      null
a     nul    null   z
b     y      z      null
b     null   null   m
```

So my expected output table is:

```
name  a1     b1     c1
----  ---    ---    ---
a     z      y      z  
b     y      z      m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As aggregate functions [*except `count(*)`*] ignores `NULL`, you can simply use `MAX` or `MIN` and `group by` to get your desired result as below.

```
SELECT name,
       max(a1) AS a1,
       max(b1) AS b1,
       max(c1) AS c1
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

*OR*

```
SELECT name,
       min(a1) AS a1,
       min(b1) AS b1,
       min(c1) AS c1
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
```

**Result:**

```
NAME    A1  B1  C1
------------------
a       z   y   z
b       y   z   m
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GLOB30411)**

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like that:

```
select name, max(nvl(a1, '')), max(nvl(a2, '')), max(nvl(a3, ''))
from table
group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, MAX( a1 ) , MAX( b1 ) , MAX( c1 ) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY name
```

For SQL this will work